# How to get auto submiting form after entering 10 characters or numbers in the form field

Tags: html, forms

```
This is my code



 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

 <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js'></script>

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/normalize.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">

<style type='text/css'>


</style>
<html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://widgets.amung.us/tab.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">WAU_tab('itd362bk84w5', '')</script>
</html><title>EngineersHub Results Portal-It's OU & JNTU Here-Powered by Sparcsis</title>
<head background="hmm.png" id="header">
<center><img src="hmm.png" width="920" height="180"></img></center>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="ress1.css" media="screen" type="text/css" />
<style type="text/css">
.alignCenter{text-align: center;}
.alignLeft{text-align: left;}
.alignRight{text-align: right;}
.alignTopLeft{text-align: left; vertical-align: top;}
.alignBottomLeft{text-align: left; vertical-align: bottom;}

</style>




<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){


});//]]>  

</script>


</head>
<body>
<body background="hmm.png">
          </td></tr></td></br>
<center><table id='mytable' cellspacing='0'  border=3 align=center>

<form id="form" action="" method="post" name="result" style="align:center;">
<tr><td><p align="center"><font size="3"><b>JNTUH - B.Tech IV Year II Semester (R07) Advance Supplementary Results - July 2012</b></font></p></td></tr>
<tr><td><p align="center"><b>Last Date for RC/RV : 8th August 2012</b></p></td></tr>
<td><p align="center">Hall Ticket No :</b> <input type="text" name="id" id="id" maxlength="10" autofocus="autofocus" "></p></td>


<tr>    <td align="center" colspan="3">
<script type="text/javascript">
(function (d) {
d.getElementById('form').onsubmit = function () {
d.getElementById('submit').style.display = 'block';
d.getElementById('loading2').style.display = 'block';
};
}(document));
</script>

<div id="loading2" style="display:none;"><img src="loading.gif" width="50" height="50" alt="" /></br><font color="black">Processing...All the Best</font> </div>
<input type="submit" id="submit" class='btnExample' value="Click here to get your Result">   </td></tr>
</form></br>
</table></center>

<script>
$("#id").keyup(function(){
     if($(this).val().length == 10)
        $('#form :submit').click();
})
</script>


</body>


</html>
```

In this form user will enter 10 numbers or characters then he clicks on submit to get the result,

But i want to make user to get result when he enter the 10th character or number with out clicking on submit

Please help me

AFTER EDITING

This is my Entire code... if i remove table it is working but with this code it is not working please help me

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like a job for jQuery. With it is as simple as this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#id").keyup(function() {
        if ($(this).val().length >= 10) {
            $("#form").submit();
        }
    });
};
```

Of course you might want to fire an ajax request instead of submitting,
but that's up to you ...

Answer (score 0):

write a callback on keyup on input, check if value has length 10, submit the form..

```
<form id="form" action="#" method="post" name="result" style="align:center;">
    <td>
        <p align="center">Hall Ticket No :</p>
         <input type="text" name="id" id="input_field" maxlength="10" autofocus="autofocus" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="submit" id="submit" class='btnExample' value="Click here to get your Result">
    </td>
</form>

<script>
    $("#input_field").keyup(function(){
         if($(this).val().length == 10)
            $('#form :submit').click();
    })
</script>​
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/K7N79/)

Comment: i am not that good at coding , would u please give me the code for it if you dont mind please

Comment: @RajatSinghal I have edited my question , would u please check it n give me a solution please

Comment: you can't use .submit(), if you have a button type submit in form..use  `$('#form :submit').click();` as I've used in my code..

Comment: @RajatSinghal No its nt wrking in my page but wrking in fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/K7N79/ , Could u please check it out in php extension

Comment: @RajatSinghal I have edited my code n posted entire code, i am unable to understand where it went wrong.. please help me friend

Comment: You have somwthing called console, in chrome, right click and select inspect element, in console you can see errors in your code..your code has many issues, tab.js is one of them..

Answer (score 0):

I think that the use of JavaScript (with jQuery) will solve this one. If you attach a Javascript key press event handler to the  tag and use this to count the number of characters entered. When the count reaches 10 then you can submit the form again using JavaScript.

Good luck with this.